# Using Java Media Framework (JMF) to create video from array of BufferedImages

Tags: java, jmf

I am working on an interactive visualization software using Java. Each frame, I display a new `BufferedImage` and save the previous `BufferedImage` in an array. I want to add a recording functionality. So, I would like to convert my array of `BufferedImage`s into any JMF-supported video format (at any configurable resolution) using the JMF library. How can I accomplish this?

I have tried looking for tutorials, but I couldn't find any that explained how I could use JMF to create a video from images...

Comment: *"I would like to convert my array of BufferedImages into any video format (at any configurable resolution) using the JMF library."* I have used JMF to turn a group of image files (JPG) into a Quicktime MOV, but it is very old and has limited support for codecs, so unless you can find an SPI (Service Provider Interface) for the more modern codecs (for reading/displaying or writing video formats), it's likely JMF will not support it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I edited my question to clarify it.

Comment: *"I would like to convert my array of BufferedImages into **any JMF-supported** video format"* Search on [jpegimagestomovie](https://www.google.com/search?q=jpegimagestomovie) for a start. Several times I've gone to alter that source code to work with raw `BufferedImage` objects, but the code is torturous and all attempts were abandoned.